# Why do $ and [ on a data frame column give different output presentation and data types?

Tags: r, vector, dataframe, printing, extract

I'm new to R. Just learning via online tutorials. My question is:

1) Why does accessing the same column with different syntaxes have different output presentation?

Vertical Display:

```
> airquality["Ozone"]
    Ozone
1      41
2      36
3      12
```

Horizontal Display:

```
airquality$Ozone
[1]  41  36  12  18  NA  28  23  19   8 
[46]  NA  21  37  20  12  13  NA  NA  NA
[91]  64  59  39   9  16  78  35  66 122
```

2) Why do the following have different data types?

```
> class(airquality["Ozone"])
[1] "data.frame"
> class(airquality$Ozone)
[1] "integer"
> class(airquality[["Ozone"]])
[1] "integer"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-and-notations-for-accessing-the-elements-of-a-lis

Comment: @jogo: No, that question is about accessing lists, not dataframes. (Yeah we know dataframes are also implemented as lists, under-the-hood, but that'll blow new users minds. Anyway the syntax for slicing dataframes is different, it allows an optional row-index too)

Comment: @jogo: actually, its title is misleading (I just fixed it), the body does say "list or dataframe". However it doesn't mention '$' so it's not a superset of this. Also it doesn't have any code example so it sucks as a canonical question. Sigh... How the hell has one of the most basic R questions been here for 8 years and nobody bothered to fix the title?

Comment: And you can't do `vector$index`. But you can do `dataframe$colname`

Comment: @smci I gave the link as additional information - not meaning that the question is a dupe of it.

Comment: @jogo oh I see. Isn't it weird that we can't seem to find any canonical question...?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Same reason for both: `airquality["Ozone"]` returns a dataframe, whereas `airquality$Ozone` returns a vector. `class()` shows you their object types. `str()` is also good for succinctly showing you an object.

See the help on the ['[' operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html), which is also known as 'extracting', or the function `getElement()`. In R, you can call `help()` on a special character or operator, just surround it with quotes: `?'['` or `?'$'` (In Python/C++/Java or most other languages we'd call this 'slicing').

As to why they print differently, [`print(obj)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.html) in R dispatches under-the-hood an object-specific print method. In this case: **[`print.dataframe`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/print.dataframe.html)**, which prints the dataframe column(s) vertically, with row-indices, vs **`print`** (or **`print.default`**) for a vector, which just prints the vector contents horizontally, with no indices.

Now back to extraction with the '[' vs '$' operators:

> The most important distinction between ‘[’, ‘[[’ and ‘$’ is that the ‘[’ can select more than one element whereas the other two ’[[’ and ‘$’ select a single element.

There's also a '[[' extract syntax, which will do like '$' does in selecting a single element (vector):

```
airquality[["Ozone"]]
[1]  41  36  12  18
```

The difference between `[["colname"]]` and `$colname` is that in the former, the column-name can come from a variable, but in the latter, it must be a string. So `[[varname]]` would allow you to index different columns depending on value of `varname`.

Read the doc about the `exact=TRUE` and `drop=TRUE` options on `extract()`. Note `drop=TRUE` only works on arrays/matrices, not dataframes, where it's ignored:

```
airquality["Ozone", drop=TRUE]
In `[.data.frame`(airquality, "Ozone", drop = TRUE) :
  'drop' argument will be ignored
```

It's all kinda confusing, offputting at first, eccentrically different and quirkily non-self-explanatory. But once you learn the syntax, it makes sense. Until then, it feels like hitting your head off a wall of symbols.

Please take a very brief skim of [R-intro](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html) and [R-lang#Indexing](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Indexing) HTML or in PDF. Bookmark them and come back to them regularly. Read them on the bus or plane...

PS as @Henry mentioned, strictly when accessing a dataframe, we should insert a comma to disambiguate that the column-names get applied to columns, not rows: `airquality[, "Ozone"]`. If we used numeric indices, `airquality[,1]` and `airquality[1]` both extract the Ozone column, whereas `airquality[1,]` extracts the first row. R is applying some cleverness since usually strings aren't row-indices.

Anyway, it's all in the doc... not necessarily all contiguous or clearly-explained... welcome to R :-)

Comment: Also worth comparing what you get from `airquality["Ozone"]` (a dataframe) with what you get with an extra comma `airquality[, "Ozone"]` (a vector like `airquality$Ozone`)  while both `airquality[c("Ozone","Temp")]` and `airquality[, c("Ozone","Temp")]` give dataframes

Comment: Thanks "smci". Your explanation makes a lot of sense. Its true that all these varieties are confusing, especially why-when it will be required? As of now, I think, this variety is provided to give more freedom to programmers over data manipulation. I think, all this variety will make sense once I get more into complex data manipulations Thanks for the document links. Much to go.

Comment: You're welcome. My suggested quickstart is skim the manuals, and read any of the hundreds of quickstart guides or tutorials out there (try a few, if you don't like one, read another). Also, know how to get `help()` on any operator, function or package. And look at `vignette('PackageName')` for a quickstart on a particular package. And use SO, R-bloggers, github, Kaggle etc. to find good code examples.